# gitpython's clone_from() throws exceptions while cloning a repo when called through an flask API

Tags: git, github, python-3.6, gunicorn, gitpython

I have python snippet which clones a github repo over https access tokens, creates a branch modifies the content, and pushes back. Below code works perfectly fine if run directly via python interpreter on command line. But I have a use case where I m exposing this functionality as an API via python's flask server. Flask server is run through a python's "gunicorn" framework which is a Python WSGI HTTP Server. Now when I use the API call, it is throwing errors while cloning the repo.
I have tested it by only running the flask server and the API call works perfectly fine and does the work without raising exceptions. But the same flask when run through gunicorn I m getting this error.

Not sure how to get rid of that error.

Code Snippet:

```
    import git
    .........
    .........
    .........
    try:
        _repo = git.Repo.clone_from(
            f"https://{_token}:x-oauth-basic@{self.git_url}", _repo_dir
        )
        _new_branch = _repo.create_head(_branch)
        _repo.head.set_reference(_new_branch)
    except Exception as e:
        return False, str(e)
    _update_path = os.path.join(
        _repo_dir, f"repo1/config/"
    )
    if not os.path.exists(_update_path):
        os.mkdir(_update_path)
    with open(f"{_update_path}/users.json", "w+") as _fd:
        json.dump(_users_json, _fd, indent=4)
    _repo.git.add(A=True)
    _repo.git.commit(m=_title)
    _repo.git.push("origin", _branch)
```

ERROR:

```
2020-06-11 17:18:16,714 DEBUG: Popen(['git', 'clone', '-v', 'https://<ACCESS_TOKEN>:x-oauth-basic@github.com/ganesh/repo1.git', '/tmp/folder-1234_1591895896.185123'], cwd=/opt/ganesh, universal_newlines=True, shell=None, istream=None)
2020-06-11 17:18:16,739 DEBUG: Cmd(['git', 'clone', '-v', 'https://<ACCESS_TOKEN>:x-oauth-basic@github.com/ganesh/repo1.git', '/tmp/folder-1234_1591895896.185123'])'s unused stdout: Cloning into '/tmp/folder-1234_1591895896.185123'...

2020-06-11 17:18:16,740 DEBUG: AutoInterrupt wait stderr: b'Error reading command stream\n'
```

Appreciate any help with this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved. It was happening with gunicorn because the it was running the flask server in daemonized mode by creating multiple workers. The gitpython codebase,

> https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/blob/24cd6dafc0008f155271f9462ae6ba6f0c0127a4/git/repo/base.py#L953-L960

is expecting some stream to read its every output. But in case of a daemonized process, there was no output stream listener and clone_from module raise exceptions.

I resolved the issue by setting a few options in the gunicorn side that lets it capture these streams.

```
--enable-stdio-inheritance \
--error-logfile /tmp/gunicorn_error.log \
--capture-output \
```

This issue has been raised in gitpython repository as to why this behavior is exhibited in the case of missing output stream readers.

> https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/issues/1020